# linked lists implementation of stack

Tags: c, pointers, stack, singly-linked-list

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct node_type {
    int data;
    struct node_type *next;
};

struct stack_type{
    node_type *top;
    int length;
};

void push(node_type *head,stack_type stack);

int main()
{
    struct stack_type stack;
    node_type *list;
    list = (node_type *)malloc(sizeof(node_type));
    list->next = NULL;
    node_type *head;
    head = list;
    stack.length = 0;   //set stack empty
    push(head, stack);
    list = head->next;
    printf("The entegers are:");
    do {
        printf("%d", stack.top->data);
        list = list->next;
        stack.top = list;
    } while (list->next != 0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void push(node_type *head,stack_type stack)
{
    int i, n;
    node_type *p;
    p = (node_type*)malloc(sizeof(node_type));
    p = head;
    printf("Enter the integers(0 to end):");
    for (;;) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n == 0)
            break;
        stack.top->data = n;
        p->next = stack.top;
        stack.length++;
    }
}
```

when I debug, it said that p->next=NULL and stop,I'm not clear about this.

why I wrong? How to fix it, I'm not clear about the use of NULL and top finger
Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: In which specific section it is stopping ?

Comment: This is not proper stack operation....Proper implementation of stack should be : there should be a "push(item, top)" function to push the elements and "pop(top)" function to show the elements

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code. You don't initialise the variables properly; you allocate a node for an empty list; you allocate to `p` in `push` and then immediately overwrite the handle to the allocated data; you pass the stack struct by value, thus not reflecting any changes that will be made by `push`and ´pop`; you use external variables for the nodes whereas the whole stack should be defined by the members of the stack struct. There's no simple fix for this program, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: First in the `main` function you don't initialize `stack.top` meaning it will have an *indeterminate* value, dereferencing this seemingly random pointer like you do in the `push` function will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The second problem is that you pass the `stack` structure to `push` *by value*, which means that it's copied and all changes done in the `push` function is only done on the local copy of the structure. You need to emulate passing *by value* by using pointers and the address-of operator `&`.

Answer (score 2):

The program does not make sense.

It is written used C constructions but compiled like a C++ program.

Function `push` is entirely wrong.

```
void push(node_type *head,stack_type stack)
{
    int i, n;
    node_type *p;
    p = (node_type*)malloc(sizeof(node_type));
    p = head;
    //...
```

The stack is accepted by value. Thus the original stack will not be changed. There is a memory leak because pointer `p` is reassigned after allocating memory. Data member `top` of the object `stack` was not initialized. So this statement

```
stack.top->data = n;
```

results in undefined behaviour of the program.

First of all you should compile your program as a C program. In this case the compiler will report numerous errors because there is no declaration of names 
`node_type` and `stack_type`.
So even the second structure declaration is invalid

```
struct stack_type{
    node_type *top;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int length;
};
```

There must be

```
struct stack_type{
    struct node_type *top;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int length;
};
```

Function `push` should be declared at least like

```
void push( struct stack_type *stack, int data );
```

It should do just one thing: push the vakue of `data` in the stack.

Take into account that the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The definition of the function `push` can look the following way

```
void push( struct stack_type *stack, int data );

int main( void )
{
    struct stack_type stack = { NULL, 0 };

    //...

    int data;

    while ( scanf( "%d", &data ) == 1 && data != 0 )
    {
        push( &stack, data );
    }
    //...
}

void push( struct stack_type *stack, int data )
{
    struct node_type *node = malloc( sizeof( struct node_type ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = stack->top;
        stack->top = node;
        ++stack->length;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have to use a linked list to imply the stack.

Comment: @jesse左 I have not understood wht you wanted to say. I showed you even the function push implementation. So what you need is to copy and paste the code in my post.